# How to count mysql with join?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I,m using laravel to developer a sales dashboard, there is a need to count the number of sales per day. I have two tables, products and transactions. In products I have all products and in transactions I have all transactions of sales

with this querie I have the numbers of sales group by product_name.

```
$dash = Transactions::select(DB::raw('`product_name` AS ProductName, COUNT(`cod_sale`) as `TotalSale`'))
        ->where('status_sale', '=', 'Finished')
        ->where('date_finished', '>=', $data)
        ->groupBy('product_name')
        ->get();
```

This querie return

```
[
  {
    "ProductName": "Product A",
    "TotalSale": 15
  },
  {
    "ProductName": "Product B",
    "TotalSale": 2
  },
  {
    "ProductName": "Product C",
    "TotalSale": 1
  },
  {
    "ProductName": "Product D",
    "TotalSale": 9
  }
]
```

How do I return products that did not sell to show zero? remembering that in the table transactions are only the products that sold and in the table products are all the products

I want to return this way:

```
[
  {
    "ProductName": "Product A",
    "TotalSale": 15
  },
  {
    "ProductName": "Product B",
    "TotalSale": 2
  },
  {
    "ProductName": "Product C",
    "TotalSale": 1
  },
  {
    "ProductName": "Product D",
    "TotalSale": 9
  },
  {
    "ProductName": "Product E",
    "TotalSale": 0
  },
  {
    "ProductName": "Product F",
    "TotalSale": 0
  }
```

Comment: you basically need left join of your products table with transactions table.

Comment: You need records of `Product E` and `Product F` to exist

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Product::leftJoin('transactions', function($join) use($date) {
        $join->on('products.id', '=', 'transactions.product_id')
            ->where('status_sale', 'Finished')
            ->where('date_finished', '>=', $date);
    })
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get([
        'products.name as ProductName',
        DB::raw('count(transactions.id) TotalSale')
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code may will help you

```
$dash = Transactions::select(DB::raw('`product_name` AS ProductName, COUNT(`cod_sale`) as `TotalSale`'))
    ->where('status_sale', '=', 'Finished')
    ->where('date_finished', '>=', $data)
    ->where(DB::raw('COUNT(`cod_sale`)' '>', 0)
    ->groupBy('product_name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: That did not return the products that did not sell

Comment: what do you want could not under stand

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not do any of the tips, I ended up learning other things, it was useful! But I decided to make the system insert in the table transactions all products every day with the number of sales = 0 and I changed the count function to SUM, so it adds the sales amount of a certain product and not more the number of lines in the table.